# Eclipse helios is not starting in Windows

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin

I have downloaded the latest zip eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32.zip, and just clicked on eclipse.exe after extracting the content.

It throws the following Exception in the logs.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-06-01 14:31:39.656
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: D:\softwares\eclipse-helios\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.compare.win32_1.0.100.I20100505-1245.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:264)

Comment: Can you give us more background about the exception, it is little hard to determine what is the problem? Of course, you can also check whether the zip file is actually existing and can be opened with standard archive utility, but I suppose you already did this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah... It's wrong binaries. I have downloaded the one for 64bit instead of 32 bit. My bad. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a "Too many open files" message in your error log? A quick search on the web showed me that this message usually pops up if there are too many opened jar files.
Try adding the following line to your configuration\config.ini file and see if it helps:

osgi.bundlefile.limit=100

Comment: Ah... It's wrong binaries. I have downloaded the one for 64bit instead of 32 bit. My bad. :-)